# mobile changePage error: unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have aspx page which has:

```
<li><a href="switchPage('#intro', 'pop', false);" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="check" class="ui-btn-right">Welkom</a></li>
```

Also I have js file which has:

```
function switchPage(pageref, method, reverseP)
{
$.mobile.changePage(pageref, {transition: method, reverse: reverseP, changeHash:  true});
}
```

When I click on link I get this exception:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-url='intro','pop', false]')

Previously I used jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js with this code:

```
<li><a href="JavaScrit:switchPage('#intro', 'pop', false)" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="check" class="ui-btn-right">Welkom</a></li>
```

And it was working. But then I wanted to use knockout library and newest versions of jquery and jquery.mobile. And when I switched to 1.1.0.min.js it stopped to work.

Comment: Forgot one thing: I'm using jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js and jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. I used different version of mobile jquery and css

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead `<a href="javascript:switchPage('#intro', 'pop', false)">`. That should work for you but please note that it would be better to bind your code to a click event. Or even better utilize the necessary data attributes.

```
<a href="#intro" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse">Welkom</a>
```

Comment: Please take a look at first post, I added new info

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters but another thing i noticed is that you are using jquery 1.7.2. The recommended version is 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, I had the same issue and almost couldn't figure it out:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="switchPage('#intro', 'pop', false)" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="check" class="ui-btn-right">Welkom</a></li>
```